# How to fix JSON Data not populating in HTML Table

Tags: php, html, json, api

I built an application that outputs json data showing who represents you in congress, using php. I created a table to output the data however, it's not rendering, not sure where the error is?

```
<div class="data-table-wrapper">
<?php

$json_rep = 
file_get_contents('https://whoismyrepresentative.com/getall_mems.php?zip='.$_GET['zip'].'&output=json');
$rep_array = json_decode($json_rep);
var_dump($rep_array);

?>
   <table class="data-table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
      <td>Party</td>
      <td>State</td>
      <td>District</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>Office</td>
      <td>Link</td>


    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($rep_array->results->Name->Party as $key=>$item){
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item->party; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item->state; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item->district; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item->phone; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item->office; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $item->link; ?></td>




  </tr>
 <?

   }
 ?>
   </table>
       </div>
        </div>
```

**should render key and value pair into the table?**

Comment: What is the expected output? Right now you have 6 columns. The header row shows the key names. The other rows show the corresponding values. Is there any problem with the content in those columns? What does "is not rendering" mean? What is the output you get? Any errors? It is nice that you debug with `var_dump`. But it would be nicer if you would reveal to us what it outputs...

Comment: use `true` in your `json_decode()` to get an associative array back. Then you can use `foreach` to loop over your array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$rep_array = json_decode($json_rep, true);` to get an associative array back. Now all you need to do is loop through the array to render any of the data in your table, like so:

```
<?php
$json_rep = file_get_contents('https://whoismyrepresentative.com/getall_mems.php?zip=10001&output=json');
$rep_array = json_decode($json_rep, true);

echo "<table>";
foreach ($rep_array['results'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key1;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value1;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: this works however, not with the 'get' method in the url, on the front end there is a form with a get method for the zipcode the user inputs. <section class="form-one">
    <form action="search-results.php" method="get">
        <label for="zipcode"> Input Zipcode</label>
        <input id="zipcode" type="number" name="zip" size="5">
        <input type="submit" name="">
    </form>
</section>

Comment: on the back-end file_get_contents('https://whoismyrepresentative.com/getall_mems.php?zip='.$_GET['zip'].'&output=json'); /* the GET method would be needed in order to get the json data for the users zipcode, is that so?

Comment: Nevermind it works, i must have made a mistake in my code.

Comment: Works with 'GET' file_get_contents <?php
$json_rep = file_get_contents('https://whoismyrepresentative.com/getall_mems.php?zip='.$_GET['zip'].'&output=json');
$rep_array = json_decode($json_rep, true);

echo "<table>";
foreach ($rep_array['results'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key1;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value1;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>